# WARNING: Can't Create a List File '/var/www/html/file_here.xml.tmp': Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, nginx

```
land@ns331252:/var/www/html$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug  5 02:39 .
drwxrwxrwx 7 root root 4096 Aug  6 07:27 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 land land 8839 Aug  5 02:39 file.here.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  612 Aug  4 12:49 index.nginx-debian.html
```

I did `chmod 775 /var/www/`
aswell tried `chmod 777 /var/www/`

Still problem persist.
I also try to create a dir…

```
31252:/var/www/html$ mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Permission denied
```

Not sure why I still get permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 5 02:39 .`

This directory belongs to root:root and does not have write permissions for group or others set. Do you see the problem now?

Comment: Yes I do, The files That id like to be written is From *Land* user how would I go about it ?

Comment: For example, without making the directory world-writeable: `sudo touch /var/www/html/file_here.xml.tmp`, `sudo chown Land /var/www/html/file_here.xml.tmp` If that file is deleted again you run into the same problem, and so, you **must** change the permissions of the directory: `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html`

Comment: Or you could change the owner of that directory. From a security standpoint, I'd probably change the user rather than allowing world to write into a directory owned by root. Usually I just have the owner of the /var/www directory be pi:www-data